"Undetectable" and non-Quest Shrines
I have 6 of 120 Shrines left to find. I know, from cross-referencing, that 2 of these are Shrine Quests.
Can I rely on the Sheikah Slate sensor to find the remaining 4?
Is it only the Shrine Quests that have the Shrine Pedestal that makes their location obvious?
This question is similar (not sure what a Heroic Quest is) and mentions one Shrine that possibly does not activate the sensor.

As someone who's played over a hundred hours of BotW, I don't think there's anything in the game called a "Heroic Quest." It's possible they played in a different language, where the term 'heroic quest' does exist, and is translated as something else when playing with the English language. A brief google search doesn't show anything either. Also, addressing a part of your question, I don't think we'd be able to tell you if your Sheikah Slate could detect the remaining shrines if we don't know what those shrines are.

There are at least three (and counting) Shrines that are neither detected by the Sheikah Slate nor have an associated quest in the Log that directs you to the location.
There is at least one Shrine Quest that is started and finished in the same location and has no visible Shrine Pedestal.
The spoiler only contains a rough location. I won't give the exact locations because there are plenty of maps/guides.
Undetectable Shrines

Sho Dantu Shrine (visible Shrine Pedestal)


 On the border between the Gerudo Desert and the Gerudo Highlands


Tho Kayu Shrine (no visible Shrine Pedestal)


 In the far west of the Gerudo Desert


Saas Ko'sah Shrine (no visible Shrine Pedestal)


 Accessed from within Hyrule Castle

No Pedestal Shrine Quests

Joloo Nah Shrine


 The eastern border of the Gerudo Highlands and Central Hyrule

If anyone has other Shrine to add, please comment with the name and I'll update my answer.

Isn't Joloo Nah related to Test of will quest?

Yes, but you get Test of Will at the location, you're not directed to the location by some other means. It's possible Bayge mentions the location after you complete "The Gut Check Challenge" but I cannot check.

But you said that these above shrines don't "have an associated quest in the Log", which is incorrect imho.

i hate the test of will shrine it was SO annoying

@pinckerman if you go on and read the second sentence/paragraph... and note the header "No Pedestal Shrine Quests" above Joloo Nah.
